# If a sentence $\varphi$ is true in all enumerable models, then is $\varphi$ true in all non-enumerable models too?

Tags: logic, proof-explanation, first-order-logic, solution-verification, model-theory

If a sentence $\varphi$ is true in all enumerable models, then is $\varphi$ true in all non-enumerable models too?

If a sentence $\varphi$ is true in all enumerable models, then $\varphi$ is true in all denumerable models. Then by Upward Lowenheim Skolem Theorem, does this entail that $\phi$ is true in all non-denumerable models as well?

Comment: See the answers to your [previous post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3619150/if-a-set-of-sentences-gamma-has-an-infinite-model-then-it-has-a-denumerable)

Comment: Let me stress again that the distinction you're making between "enumerable" and "denumerable" is very non-standard and very confusing.

Comment: What's the standard distinction? 'enumerable' for finite or denumerable and 'non-enumerable' for non-denumerable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your previous question, for you "enumerable" means countable = finite or countably infinite, and "denumerable" means countably infinite.

So you you want to prove that if a sentence $\varphi$ is true in all countable structures, then $\varphi$ is true in all uncountably infinite structures. It would suffice to prove the stronger statement that if a sentence $\varphi$ is true in all countably infinite structures, then $\varphi$ is true in all uncountably infinite structures. Applying Upward Löwenheim-Skolem doesn't help, because it only gives you *some* model of $\varphi$ in each uncountable cardinality.

Instead, let's prove the contrapositive of this statement: If a sentence $\varphi$ is false in some uncountably infinite structure, then $\varphi$ is false in some countably infinite structure.

If $\varphi$ is false in some uncountably infinite structure, then $\lnot \varphi$ has an uncountably infinite model. Now we just have to apply the Downward Löwenheim-Skolem theorem to $\lnot \varphi$ to get a countably infinite model. So $\varphi$ is false in some countably infinite structure.

This argument assumes the language is countable. The statement may not be true in an uncountable language.

---

Regarding terminology: "enumerable" and "denumerable". The problem is that conventions are not universal. Here's my experience, I welcome comments from others with different experiences!

There are two notions we want to name, which I'll refer to in this post as "countably infinite" and "finite or countably infinite".

These days, almost no one says "enumerable" *or* "denumerable". They say "countable". Now "countable" may mean "countably infinite" or "finite or countably infinite" depending on the author. If "countable" means "countably infinite", then the author would refer to the other notion as "finite or countable" or "at most countable". If "countable" means "finite or countably infinite", then the author would refer to the other notion as "countably infinite".

Some authors use "countable" and "denumerable" for the two notions, or "countable" and "enumerable" for the two notions. But again, you'd have to check the conventions. To make things worse, "denumerable" and "enumerable" have both been commonly used as synonyms for "countable", so that all three words can mean the same thing. I think the most common usage of "enumerable" these days is in the notion of "recursively enumerable" from computability theory, which is something quite different.

My main complaint was that you're using "enumerable" and "denumerable" for the two notions. I think this is really confusing, because the words sound so similar. It's hard to remember which one means which notion. If you've learned this convention from some source, I'd be curious to know what it is.

Comment: Currently I'm learning from Computability and Logic by George Boolos, John P. Burgess, and Richard Jeffrey. See Ch.1 on Enumerability.

Comment: @HarryRothschild I see! Well, I think Boolos, Burgess, and Jeffrey have made a very confusing terminological choice here.

Comment: @AlexKruckman here is my first experience that we saw in Walter Rudin Analysis's textbook: Let $J_{n}$ be the set that its elements belong to $\mathbb{Z}^+$ and $ J $ be the set including all integers $\mathbb{Z} $.

Comment: For any arbitrary set $A$, we say 

1- $A $ is " finite " if $A \sim J_{n}$ ( for some $n$ ). ( and $\sim$ is the notation of 1-1 correspondence relation between two sets, as we had in elementary set theory ).

Comment: 2- The negation of the first case means $A$ is " infinite ", namely $A$ is infinite if it is not finite.

Comment: 3- $A$ is " countable " if $A \sim J$ and the case 4- $A$ is " uncountable " if it is neither finite nor countable.

Comment: 5- $A$ is " at most countable " if $A$ is finite or countable.

Comment: @MaryamAjorlou Ah yes, "at most countable" is also a common terminology. I'll add it to my post. In general, I think Rudin's conventions are very common and very sensible.

Comment: @AlexKruckman, I googled to see if there exists a standard convention or not. One point  I saw was that, if the axiom of choice holds, then the law of trichotomy holds for cardinality. So we can make the following definitions: finite set, countably infinite set, uncountable set.

Comment: @MaryamAjorlou If "uncountable" means "not finite or countably infinite", then you don't need the axiom of choice to show that every set is finite, countably infinite, or uncountable. You only need propositional logic! The role of trichotomy is for cardinality is to show that the uncountable sets are actually "bigger" than the countable sets, in the sense that every uncountable set has a countably infinite subset.